# Haskell - how to open file if it's provided or use stdin instead

Tags: haskell

I am trying to open file if it exists or use stdin instead. I want to call hGetContents on hInFile united. This is what I came up with, but don't know how to make it work.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let (inFileExists, inFile) = procArgs args
    if inFileExists 
        then hInFile <- openFile inFile ReadMode --this gives me parse error
        else let hInFile = stdin
    input' <- hGetContents hInFile
    print hInFile
    return ()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if` is an expression so the branches also have to be expressions which `... <- ...` and `let ... = ...` are not. Instead I would do something like

```
hInFile <- if inFileExists 
           then openFile inFile ReadMode
           else return stdin
```

where `return stdin` says "just give me back `stdin`", it's needed to make all the types work out though.